# Making Graphite UI data cumualtive by default

Tags: graph, graphite, statsd

I'm setting up Graphite, and hit a problem with how data is represented on the screen when there's not enough pixels.

I found [this post](https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/161034) whose first answer is very close to what I'm looking for:

> No what is probably happening is that you're looking at a graph with more datapoints than pixels, which forces Graphite to aggregate the datapoints. The default aggregation method is averaging, but you can change it to summing by applying the cumulative() function to your metrics.

Is there any way to get this cumulative() behavior by default?

I've modified my storage-aggregation.conf to use 'aggregationMethod = sum', but I believe this is for historical data and not for data that's displayed in the UI.

When I apply cumulative() everything is perfect, I'm just wondering if there's a way to get this behavior by default.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that even though you've modified your storage-aggregation.conf to use 'aggregationMethod = sum', your metrics you've already created have not changed their aggregationMethod.  The rules in storage-aggregation.conf only affect new metrics.

To change your existing metrics to be summed instead of averaged, you'll need to use whisper-resize.py.  Or you can delete your existing metrics and they'll be recreated with sum.

Here's an example of what you might need to run:

```
whisper-resize.py --xFilesFactor=0.0 --aggregationMethod=sum /opt/graphite/storage/whisper/stats_counts/path/to/your/metric.wsp 10s:28d 1m:84d 10m:1y 1h:3y
```

Make sure to run that as the same user who owns the file, or at least make sure the files have the same ownership when you're done, otherwise they won't be writeable for new data.

Another possibility if you're using statsd is that you're just using metrics under stats instead of stats_counts.  From the [statsd README](https://github.com/etsy/statsd):

> In the legacy setting rates were recorded under stats.counter_name
>   directly, whereas the absolute count could be found under
>   stats_count.counter_name. With disabling the legacy namespacing those
>   values can be found (with default prefixing) under
>   stats.counters.counter_name.rate and stats.counters.counter_name.count
>   now.

Basically, metrics are aggregated differently under the different namespaces when using statsd, and you want stuff under stats_count or stats.counters for things that should be summed.